# How to bind a Tooltip's content to an MVVM property within code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

Due the nature of our software, we have to create our datagrid columns dynamically in code behind and add it then to the datagrid like this:

```
DataGridBoundColumn dataGridBoundColumn = new DataGridTextColumn
                                                          {
                                                              CellStyle = ...,                                                                            
                                                              Header = header,
                                                              Binding = binding
                                                          };
reportDataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridBoundColumn);
```

Now we need a tooltip on the columnheader:

```
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(dataGridBoundColumn, "ENTER VALUE");
```

Well that works fine too. However I need to bind the tooltip's value to a property on the ViewModel.  I know how to do this in the xaml, but no idea how to do that in code.

Any help would be appreciated,

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Steve's answer I was able to fix this slightly differently:

```
Binding bindingBoundToTooltipProperty = new Binding()
                                   {
                                       Source = reportDataGrid.DataContext, 
                                       Path = new PropertyPath("ToolTipSorting")
                                   };


BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridBoundColumn, ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, bindingBoundToTooltipProperty);
```

if the DataGridColumnHeaderStyle was customized, make sure to add these lines to the template as well:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Column.(ToolTipService.ToolTip), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set up a binding as below:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridBoundColumn,
    ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty,
    new Binding("Path.To.My.Property"));
```

Note: the `DataContext` of this will be the value of the `Header` property on the column

You want to bind to a property on the view model; assuming that your view model is the `DataContext` for the `DataGrid` you would want to change the binding to something like:

```
new Binding("DataContext.ToolTipSorting")
{
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor)
    {
        AncestorType = typeof(DataGrid)
    }
}
```

This attempts to locate the first parent object of type `DataGrid` and grab the value of its `DataContext.ToolTipSorting` property.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I get System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=ToolTipSorting; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=42996073); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object')

Comment: If the Datacontext is on the Header, how do I bind to the MVVM property "ToolTipSorting" on my ViewModel please?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the `DataContext` will be the `Header` property - can you leave the binding path blank to see what type the data context is in your example?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment - misunderstood.  See my update

Comment: Thank you so much Steve. It didn't work exactly like that, you gave me the right direction though. I have edited my question for the little change I had to undertake to make it work. Many thanks again for your help!